# Find 3d coordinates of a point on a line projected from another point in 3d space

Tags: swift, 3d, scenekit, arkit

Working in Swift, ARTKit / SceneKit

[image]

I have a line AB in 3d and I have xyz coordinates of both points A and B.
I also have a point C and I know its xyz coordinates too.

Now, I want to find out the xyz coordinates of point D on line AB; given that CD is perpendicular to AB.

What would be a simple way to do it in Swift.

Comment: Lines are infinitesimally narrow. Such an intersection practically doesn't exist. Your target AB line would have to have some width, making it a rectangular plane. At that point, it's just a matter to ray tracing a line to intersect a plane, which is an easy and well documented task.

Comment: @Alexander AB is actually a cylinder of radius 0.0002

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameterize the line `AB` with a scalar `t`:

```
P(t) = A + (B - A) * t`
```

The point `D = P(t)` is such that `CD` is perpendicular to `AB`, i.e. their dot product is zero:

```
dot(C - D, B - A) = 0

dot(C - A - (B - A) * t, B - A) = 0

dot(C - A, B - A) = t * dot(B - A, B - A)

// Substitute value of t

-->  D = A + (B - A) * dot(C - A, B - A) / dot(B - A, B - A)
```

Swift code:

```
var BmA = B - A
var CmA = C - A
var t = dot(CmA, BmA) / dot(BmA, BmA)
var D = A + BmA * t;
```

Comment: Btw you can type `•` with `option` + `8`

Comment: @Alexander I just wanted to distinguish between the scalar and dot products; besides I would need extra parentheses for the fraction term. But thanks for the tip, I'll make use of it in future answers.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Any chance you could translate the final equation `D = A + (B - A) * dot(C - A, B - A) / dot(B - A, B - A)` to SWIFT?

Comment: @Kashif Stackoverflow is not a substitute for a linear algebra class and graphics programming class =/

Comment: @meowgoesthedog This worked like a charm. Thank you very much!! I must add that having a SCNVector3 Extension like https://github.com/devindazzle/SCNVector3Extensions helps a lot.

Comment: @Kashif I'm not familiar with SceneKit so I was surprised that it did not have any built-in functions, but yes that is definitely the way to go.